# What methods can be used to overcome the tie-breaking when using majority voting in ensemble?

Tags: machine-learning, classification, python, ensemble-learning, ties

What methods can be used to overcome the tie-breaking when using **majority voting** in ensemble? I read that **Weighted majority voting** can help; however, it wasn't effective on the dataset I am using in terms of the F1 score and it dropped significantly.

Comment: There are about a million options here, but nobody can make a universal pronouncement about ‘best’.

Comment: More votes (ie more trees) will lead to less ties. An odd number of votes will eliminate ties in binary classification

Comment: What’s wrong with a tie? (I have my thoughts, but it will help to hear yours.)

Comment: @Dave Currently I am doing an Unsupervised binary classification (0,1). For the majority voting, I am using `mode` from `scipy`. Once I have a tie break the `mode` chooses 0 which is affecting my f1 score. I thought of adding an odd number of base learners. However, my base learners are created from two algorithms with different parameter sets. Therefore, I cant choose (favour) one algorithm over the other to break the tie

Comment: Would you prefer that some of the ties be called $1$ instead of $0$?

Comment: @Dave My aim is to use a method that breaks the ties and improve my results

Comment: But why are the ties a problem?

Comment: @Dave I think ties make the results bias

Answer (score 1, accepted):

a) count the votes, select the class with more votes

b) count the votes weighted by the confidence (or probability) the base classifier assigns to its decision. Select the class with higher weighted vote.

c) count the votes. If there is a tie (and only if there is a tie) select the class with higher weighted votes for only the classes tied as best. (I *think* sklearn uses this at least in their OVO implementation)

None of them is "best". This third one is **not** equivalent to the 2nd and so it may be worth it to try.

Comment: Point B is not clear to me/ Could you please explain it a bit more. Point C is an interesting approach, definitely I am going to try it.

Comment: Usually, classifiers output a degree do confidence (which could be a probability or another number)  for the data in relation to each class. This is the `decision_function()` method output in sklearn. Add such degrees of confidence for ach class and select the most confident.

Comment: Thank you for the explination.